# Import Errors in Replit

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, anaconda, replit

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot the "module not found error" in replit when importing torch and pyterrier to the IDE? The latest pytorch is installed to my computer but replit will not allow me to use it.

I have tried looking in system preferences in replit, and running it on other IDEs. It imported on Anaconda Jupyter notebooks but said I needed to pay for more disk space. I confirmed that it works but I want to know how to use it in an IDE where I have the disk space to handle it.

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting (if you don't know how: [code block])

Comment: {Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/IdenticalAfraidTriangles/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 174, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libcufft.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory}